# "this.source is not a function" error while implementing autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var var_name=null;
   $('#id1').click(function(){

      $.ajax({
         type:"GET",
         url:" ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.Page",
         success:function(response){
            var_name=response;
            console.log(response);
         }
      })
   });
   $("#id").autocomplete({source:var_name});
});
```

This is the Code I am messing with,It says TypeError:this.source is not a function. Where I am wrong,Correct me???[image: screenshot of Error and Json from response]

Comment: var var_name=null; instead declare var var_name=[ ];

Answer (score 11, accepted):

jQuery Ajax methods are non-blocking, so it looks like you're trying to set an auto-complete source before the previous method resolves. You probably want to move the `autocomplete` assignment into the success method of your `.ajax()` call.

So, instead of what you have, use:

```
$.ajax({
    type:       "GET",
    url:        "ggs.erm.servlet.setup5.Page",
    success:    function(response) {
        $("#id").autocomplete({ source: response });
    }
});
```

Comment: After indenting the code correctly you can even see that he put the assignment of var_name to the source property even outside of the click handler.